# Misaligned HTML in rails application

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have followed Hartl's tutorial to make a ToDoList with a tagging system, also with the help of this [word guide](https://medium.com/@sherzelsmith/add-a-filtering-multiple-tag-system-with-autocomplete-to-your-rails-model-in-rails-5-1bf88cd53e9) and [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uBa2qs9CFZQ).

However, as a consequence of making an additional page for filtered tasks, the html isn't rendering in a nice aligned manner as before. This can be seen from the footer file's image, which is not centralised, hence not aligned with the footer's sentence(which is still centralised),

[image: wrong filter]

while my home page doesn't seem to have this problem.

[image: correct filter]

Does anyone know the solution to the problem? I'm really bad with working with these html files embedded with Ruby due to the fact the rendering occurs almost everywhere. Moreover, I didn't really understand how the tutorial was able to the filtering possible the moment we click the tags. I do not need the text box as per the home page feed. Do let me know if more information is required.

Html code for involved files in log

application.html.erb(the general layout of any page)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= render 'layouts/rails_default' %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
      <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
        <%= content_tag(:div, message, class: "alert alert-#{message_type}") %>
      <% end %>
      <%= yield %>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
      <!-- <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %> -->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

<script>
  $(document).on('ready page:load', function () {
    $('#micropost_tag_ids').chosen({
      allow_single_deselect: true,
      width: '100%'
    })
  });
</script>
```

micropost/index.html.erb (Filtered Page)

```
<h1>Filtered Micropost Page</h1>
<div class = "col-md-8 offset-2">
  <% @microposts.each do |micropost| %>
    <p><%= truncate(micropost.content, length: 50) %></p>
    <p><small>Tags: <%= raw micropost.tags.map(&:name).map { |t| link_to t, tag_path(t) }.join(', ') %></small</p>
        <span class="timestamp">
            Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %> ago.
            <% if current_user?(micropost.user) %>
              <%= link_to "Done", micropost_path(micropost), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Keep up the good work!" } %>
            <% end %>
        </span>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Footer.html.erb

```
<footer class="footer">
  <small>
    A To-Do Manager</a>
    by <a href="https://www.google.com"> Prashin</a> for
    <a href = "http://www.google.com">Prashin</a>,
    based on the rails tutorial guide by
    <a href = "https://www.railstutorial.org/book">Michael Hartl</a>.
  </small>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><%= link_to "About",   about_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Contact", contact_path %></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <br>

  <br><br>
  <p align = center>
  <%= link_to image_tag("AikenDueet.jpg", alt: "KenyuDueet"),
            'www.google.com' %>
            <br>I can do it!</p>
</footer>
```

header.html.erb

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <%= link_to "To-Do App", root_path, id: "logo" %>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Users <b class="caret"></b>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><%= link_to "All Users", users_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Administrators", users_admin_path %></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <% if logged_in? %>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              Account <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><%= link_to "#{current_user.name}", current_user %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Account Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li>
                <%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: :delete %>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        <% else %>
          <li><%= link_to "Log in", login_path %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Log

```
  Rendered microposts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (199.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_rails_default.html.erb (55.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 278ms (Views: 259.1ms | ActiveRecord: 11.4ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a [bootstrap grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid) problem, you have your main content inside a div.container, but your footer is inside the same container and you don't define some columns on it.

Solution 1: Put the footer inside a row and define your columns

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
    <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Solution 2: Put your footer on its own div.container and define your columns for it

```
<div class="container">
  <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
    <%= content_tag(:div, message, class: "alert alert-#{message_type}") %>
  <% end %>
  <%= yield %>

  <!-- <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %> -->
</div>
<div class="container">
   <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
</div>
```